# wait for a background queue from another background queue ios

Tags: objective-c, grand-central-dispatch, nsthread

I'm uploading some files in s3 in a background queue and posting a message with the uploaded files as attachment. And the posting process is also running on background so that UI navigations don't get hampered. And both the queue are on different viewcontrollers.

I want to wait for the upload queue and den start post queue.

```
// in view controller 1
    dispatch_queue_t uploadQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0);
dispatch_async(uploadQueue, ^{

 // my code to upload files.
});


// in view controller 2
    dispatch_queue_t postQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0);
dispatch_async(postQueue, ^{

 // my code to post the message.
});
```

m not that much clear with this queue and source. please guide me.

Comment: so why not post the files once the upload is over in uploadQueue? i.e use 1 queue to a) upload the files synchronously, and then b) post the files

Comment: coz upload and posting is running on background queue and ui will not be waiting for any process to be completed. and more importantly upload and posting are on diff view controller so I need to communicate them accordingly. dispatch_sync queue pauses ui thread until it is completed.